# Reopen a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I have been stuggling for same time now but I don't now how to do that...

When I select a cell in column Q, I get a userform (which is ok).

In that userform I have the content of the selected cell (e.g. Q6) (which is ok)

In userform I have two buttons:
- quit: which closes the userform without saving the text in the cell;
- save: which save the text in the cell from userform.

Both at saving and quitting the selections (focus) remain on that cell (Q6).

I want when I click again on the Q6 (witch is already selected), the userform reopen again.

The only solution I found so far, is to change the selection (for exemple on P6).

Cam anyone, please, help me? Thx.

Comment: just curious why create such a simple tool and get into such trouble? If you are trying to prevent user from entering the wrong value, try invoke a msgbox to confirm or deny the changes through the `Change` event listener. If confirm, then do nothing, else `Undo` the changes.

Comment: Why not assign a shortcut key to open the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to how you are currently showing the form, you could add a double-click event handler. In the sheet's code module do something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column = Range("Q1").Column Then
        UserForm1.Show
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Instruct the users that if they want to reshow the form, they should double click on the currently selected cell.

Comment: Thank you for your quickly answer. It works, but, usually double click is used to edit cell in Excel by default, isn't it...? I don't understand that Cancel = True do and why Range("Q1") (is not a reference for cell Q1?)

Comment: `If Target.Column = 17 Then` is much simpler ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I thought of that, of course, but then the reader has to stop and figure out which column is 17. Also, it is easier to switch to another column.

Comment: @colombo2003 The point of `Cancel = True` is to override the default meaning of double clicking. I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, but I assumed that if you have a userform pop-up whenever you select a cell in column Q then for that column you don't want to edit the contents directly but instead want to go through the userform. The business about range "Q1" was just to specify the column number without using a number.